# Nginx ssl_session_cache none explanation

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

What does Nginx default configuration ssl_session_cache none mean?  If I use openssl reconnect to test it, it says the connection is reused. Since the server doesn't store any session information in case of ssl_session_cache=none, how does the session reuse work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nginx default value of `ssl_session_cache` is `none`, as you point out. It means

> the use of a session cache is gently disallowed: nginx tells a client that sessions may be reused, but does not actually store session parameters in the cache.

Sessions can be reused by storing sessions by `session_id` in the nginx server `ssl_session_cache`, ***or by being stored on the client*** side using [TLS session tickets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5077), which are enabled in nginx via the [`ssl_session_tickets` setting](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_tickets). The default value of `ssl_session_tickets` is `on`, which allows your `openssl` client to reuse the session by using the saved session ticket, which is how your `openssl` client is able to reuse the TLS session even with the session cache disabled.

Use

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -reconnect -no_ticket
```

to disable the use of session tickets by the `openssl` client and test only the session cache resumption feature of nginx.